# Gamma function approximation

Tags: ruby, gamma-function

I'm trying to write a three-parameter method that approximates the gamma function over a certain interval. The approximation should be a right-endpoint Riemann sum.

The gamma function is given by:

```
GAMMA(s) = 
inf
INT  x^(s-1) * exp(-x) dx
0
```

The right-endpoint Riemann sum approximation over the interval (0, m) should therefore be:

```
GAMMA(s) ~  
m
SUM  ((m/n)*i)^(s-1) * exp(-(m/n)*i) * delta_x        where delta_x = (m/n)
i=1
```

My code is as follows:

```
def gamma(x = 4.0, n = 100000, m = 2500)
  array = *(1..n)
  result = array.inject(0) {|sum, i| sum + ((((m/n)*i)**(x-1))*((2.7183)**(-(m/n)*i))*(m/n))}  
end

puts gamma
```

The code should return an approximation for 3! = 6, but instead it returns 0.0. Any ideas where I may be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `m/n`

you are doing an integer division (eg 3/4 = 0) when you expect a float division (3/4 = 0.75)

you need to define your `n` and `m` as floats.

You can rewrite it as

```
def gamma(x = 4.0, n = 100000, m = 2500)
  n = n.to_f
  m = m.to_f

  (1..n).to_a.inject(0) do |sum, i|
    sum + ((((m/n)*i)**(x-1))*((Math::E)**(-(m/n)*i))*(m/n))
  end  
end
```

PS: also you do not need the `array` and `result` variables.
PS2: consider using [Math::E](http://apidock.com/ruby/Math) instead of `2.7183`

Comment: I just implemented the process in excel and I got the correct answer, so I knew my approach was correct. I'm a coding n00b, so I figured it had to be that. Thanks again. This site is great.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was identified by @xlembouras. You might consider writing the method as follows.

**Code**

```
def gamma(x = 4.0, n = 100000, m = 2500)
  ratio = m.to_f/n
  xm1 = x-1.0
  ratio * (1..m).inject(0) do |sum,i|
    ixratio = i*ratio
    sum + ixratio**xm1 * Math.exp(-ixratio)
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
gamma(x=4.0, n= 40, m =10).round(6) #=> 1.616233
gamma.round(6)                      #=> 6.0
```

Please confirm these calculations are correct.

Comment: gamma(4) should equal 3! = 6

Comment: I plan on writing a method that will extend the Gamma function to the entire complex plane. The ultimate goal is to be able to then write a method that will allow me to evaluate values of the functional equation of the Riemann Zeta function.